# Angular 2+ Linter for memory leaks?

Tags: angular

Is there a profiling tool/(npm)library/developer tools extension/(mem)linter that can analyze the code (or at runtime) and alert the developer when it detects a memory leak such as forgetting to unsubscribe from an Observable subscription.

I'm aware async will auto unsubscribe. Also profiling on Chrome will give clues with memory management. In a large code base it gets time consuming chasing those down, and reviewing all components...

Is there anything like a linter for memory leaks for Angular 2+

Comment: I've never seen such a tool for any framework, do you any?

Comment: @Maximus nope, never really needed one till now

Comment: I don't think there exists one